# windows phone 7 - How to search & connect to Bluetooth devices programatically

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-7, bluetooth

I want to create an application for windows phone 7 that can search for & connect to bluetooth devices. But Compact Framework of WM7 not exposing any API to handle Bluetooth while am also not able to connect with sockets as system.net.sockets not showing any class. Any one can help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thats currently not supported in the SDK!

Answer (score 1):

In the current framework for Windows Phone 7 development there is no support for sockets and there is no API for BlueTooth, either. I doubt there will be any changes on this front before the Mango update (towards the end of this year: November-ish) and we should find out exactly what will be in Mango at [MIX](http://live.visitmix.com).

Comment: is there any way to to search & listdown bluetooth devices on wp7?

Comment: @Ashwini - There is no Bluetooth API in the current SDK at all.